# Microsoft Thumb Reader

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics

Has anyone used the Microsoft thumb reader?

Where can I find detailed API documentation for it?

Does it have a built in identification system?

Does it support Java?

Answer (score 0):

The general consensus out there is you have to go with [Griaule Biometrics's SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/fingerprint_sdk),
as per numerous [blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/06/1815291.aspx)/[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Fingerprint_Reader)

This SDK handles win/linux, java, .NET and COM

Comment: thanks for replying.IS there any simulator that stimulates microsoft thumb reader? I wanted to test how it works before i buy it.